# What's the best method to retrieve the duration of a live stream on Facebook with Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, streaming

I've been searching in google how to know the duration of a live streaming in FB by using their graph API but with no luck. Anyone has any idea ? I've already the creation time because that's a field you can use a parameter when you do the request but no clues about the ending date.

Any idea will be very appreciated

I've tried using the Facebook Graph Api but with no luck, the field i need there is no in the response